# Is Freedom of speech a legitimate Right and a Law?

Tags: law

Is freedom of speech a legitimate right that can be referred as a versus of law. I mean a rule that can be referred in courts?

If so what countries have this law? and what is it's law statement? I mean conditions, limitations and sub-notes.

edited: I mean is there any law that according to that, you can condemn someone has ignoring your freedom of speech?

Comment: Asking 'which countries have x' is a pretty broad question. I imagine a book could be written on this topic.

Comment: @userLTK. Having a clean environment is a right but you can't condemn any one for drop trashes in street. I mean is there any law that according to that, you can condemn someone has ignoring your freedom of speach?

Comment: @blip
I mainly wanna discuss this about USA and UK law, for more clearance.

Comment: @HOPE then I suggest you clarify that in your question. As for the US, it's a "legitimate" right in that it's part of the constitution (1st amendment): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech_in_the_United_States

Comment: @HOPE I don't know what you mean.   It's against the law to drop trash in the street.  It's often not enforced, but it's a ticket-able offense.    But, as for the rest of my comment above, I may have mis-read your intent in your question, by versus, I thought you meant legitimate as opposed to legal, but re-reading, I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: @userLTK you mean if you drop trash in the street, Police can arrest you? By 'versus' I mean can you condemn someone that is neglecting your freedom of speech, e.g. in a ngo? For condemning someone you need to refer to a specific part of law. by 'verses' I mean this.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the meaning of the word versus.   I didn't read carefully enough, when I re-read I saw that.   I'll delete my post.    But, I still don't get your littering argument.    It is against the law to drop trash in the street, and people can be (but rarely are) condemned for it.   Just cause it's a fine not an arrest doesn't change the law.

Comment: @userLTK. You mean there is a note in law that if a man drop trash in the street, you can arrest him or her. for example 1000$ for punishment. Is it true? I don't know that. I looked to this issue as a cultural and public respect.

Comment: @HOPE freedom of speech, at least in the US, does nothing to protect one from condemnation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the comments, I think I can provide an answer. If the question is:

> I mean is there any law that according to that, you can condemn someone has ignoring your freedom of speech?

The answer is probably “none”. Freedom of speech is not something that impose any obligations to other people, you don't have to listen to, support or otherwise enable someone's expression of their opinions. A newspaper does not have to publish anything you send them, your neighbour does not have to provide power to your sound system if you want to make a speech, etc.

In many cases, you can even severely restrict someone else's ability to express opinions in private circumstances (e.g. a company can set detailed rules regarding what employees can say during and, to some extent, outside work) and that's traditionally not regarded as a major freedom of speech issue (although democracy at work is in fact a topic of debate).

In its most basic sense, freedom of speech is about *the government* not jailing people for having said/written/published something. Depending on the country, common restrictions include libel, slander, laws protecting classified material, hate speech, threats, copyright, indecency, insults especially against officers of the law, etc.

This is a very general idea, protected in many countries (at least in principle, even if not always very effectively). One formulation can be found in the Universal Declaration of Human Rights, whose article 19 reads:

> Everyone has the right to freedom of opinion and expression; this right includes freedom to hold opinions without interference and to seek, receive and impart information and ideas through any media and regardless of frontiers.

Comment: Which is found in every country

Comment: @Relaxed. Yes, It's my exact question that you've answer it. Suppose in a meeting, when you want to say your opinions, they don't allow you to say anything. according to what you say, they are allowed to do this and there's no law that can prevent them. Is it true? Then what is freedom of speech exactly?

Comment: @HOPE It depends a little bit on the type of meeting and who “they” are. But, yes, if that's a private meeting, something a company organises, etc. then there are usually no laws preventing the organisers to chose who can talk and about what. But if like-minded people want to meet to talk about something and the police comes in to interrupt the meeting then that would certainly be regarded as an infringement on those people freedom of speech. I will add a definition to my answer, hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: Therefore freedom of speech is the right to say whatever you want (within the limits I mentioned) without fearing being arrested by the police. But nobody has to listen to you, help you say it or generally approve what you are saying or condone your saying it. Coming back to your meeting example, nobody has to let you do anything in their meeting but you should be able to set up your own meeting if you wish (the right of peaceful assembly and association is a related fundamental right).

Comment: @Relaxed I got it. freedom of speech is declared upon government actions and restrictions. If you say something with limitations you mentioned, then no government is allowed to control your opinion and speech. You made it clear. tnx.

Comment: @HOPE That's the idea, exactly.

Comment: @Relaxed, curiously, there's an argument that hate speech is protected under the constitution.   (and I'm not fan of hate-speech, in fact, I'm in favor of it being illegal), but there's a pretty grey border between hate speech and critisism - which should be protected.   Libel, Slander, deceit, threats - those aren't covered by free speech, though with is slander and what is critisism,  again, perhaps a grey border sometimes too.  Anyhoo:   https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/volokh-conspiracy/wp/2015/05/07/no-theres-no-hate-speech-exception-to-the-first-amendment/

Comment: @userLTK I am not specifically referring to the US and I did not mean that all those exceptions apply everywhere, certainly not in the same way. Those are simply common limits I observed in various countries and for hate speech I had several European countries in mind. I meant to add a few other examples incidentally, hope it's clearer now.